# WordPress: posts_per_page not working on archive pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I've a custom loop which should display 3 projects per category in a random order.
The problem is, that the loop always shows all projects in that category.

I've tested the the code on a single page and it works how it should and only showed 3 projects.

So I guess it has something to do with the archive page?!

Here's ist the loop itself:

```
<?php

        $args_thema = array (
            'post_type' => array( 'project' ),
            'orderby' => 'rand',
            'posts_per_page'    => 3,
            'paged'             => $paged,
            //'ignore_sticky_posts'    => 1,
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'project-category',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $category->slug,
                ),
            ),
        );

        $query_thema = new WP_Query( $args_thema ); if ( $query_thema->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <ul class="">
            <?php $i = 0; while ( $query_thema->have_posts() ) : $query_thema->the_post(); $i++; // echo $i; ?>
                <li class="">
                    <a class="url uid" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php else : ?>

        <?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

And here's the full code (I guess not that relevant):

```
<?php

    $args       = array('hide_empty' => '0', 'taxonomy' => 'project-category', 'orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'parent' => 0 );
    $categories = get_categories($args);

    foreach($categories as $category) {

?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">

        <?php
            $term_child = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
            $args_child = array('hide_empty' => '0', 'taxonomy' => 'project-category', 'orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'parent' => $category->term_id );
        ?>

        <h4><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($category->slug, 'project-category')  ?>" title="<?php echo $category->name ?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></a></h4>

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">

        <?php

        $args_thema = array (
            'post_type' => array( 'project' ),
            'orderby' => 'rand',
            'posts_per_page'    => 3,
            'paged'             => $paged,
            //'ignore_sticky_posts'    => 1,
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'project-category',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $category->slug,
                ),
            ),
        );

        $query_thema = new WP_Query( $args_thema ); if ( $query_thema->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <ul class="">
            <?php $i = 0; while ( $query_thema->have_posts() ) : $query_thema->the_post(); $i++; // echo $i; ?>
                <li class="">
                    <a class="url uid" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php else : ?>

        <?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    </div>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: no, there are no sticky posts

Comment: wp_reset_postdata() is already there

Comment: @Dhruv `wp_reset_postdata()` is in the correct spot.

Comment: @Cray if you aren't using pagination, you can remove the `paged` property. And instead of `posts_per_page` use `'numberposts' => 3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it was an extra function which sets the archive posts to 99.

Istead of `is_post_type_archive` I used `is_archive`

Comment: see my answer above, the problem is solved. Thanks for your help